# How do I seek to end of a kafka topic when I am creating a new consumer in an existing consumer group with akka streams?

Tags: java, scala, apache-kafka, akka, akka-stream

I have an akka application (in JAVA) that uses `commitablePartitionedSource` for consuming messages from kafka topics. I have a few consumer groups that spin up consumers for multiple topics. This is driven by a dynamic configuration where I can shutdown consumers temporarily and maybe start them back at a later point.

When this consumer restarts, I only want to read new messages and not start from where I left off.

Is there a way to get the kafkaConsumer object from akka-alpakka consumer, so that I can seekToEnd() before processing?
Please let me know if there is any other way to achieve this? Maybe with akka config or a different type of consumer? I prefer not maintaining my own offsets (Hopefully not the only option)

My config is set up to get the `latest` offset when I start a consumer group, but since I am shutting down and restarting individual consumers it always starts consuming where I left off.

I tried creating a consumer group for a topic, but I have many topics and it turns out pretty resource intensive. I also looked for a way to clear offsets stored in kafka for that topic unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would just be to create a new *consumer group* each time you start your restart your consumer. Kafka will take care of removing stale *consumer groups* after a configurable amount of time (**retention.ms**).

This strategy is fine if you rarely restart your consumer and always want it to process fresh data instead of catching up with all the missed messages.

**EDIT**

As far as I know the only way to have access to the underlying KafkaConsumer is to use a `committableExternalSource`. This way you'll have access to the `seekToEnd` method, however you'll also need take care of subscribing to the topic providing the start offset per partition (similarly as how you're doing now setting up the `committablePartitionedSource` but outside of *Akka*).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I need too many consumers for this approach sadly.

Answer (score 0):

`commitablePartitionedSource` takes `AutoSubscription` as an input, which you cannot specify offset.

What you need is a method that takes `ManualSubscription` or higher level `Subscription`, such as

```
> plainExternalSource
> committableExternalSource
> plainSource
...
```